# How can I reverse a string word by word without using arrays, split() or StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, algorithm, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a string word by word without using arrays, `split()` or `StringBuilder`. This is my code so far. It works, but my output is not how I want it. See my image for output.
I want my program to output each word on a new line. Also notice how the letter "n" is missing from curtain and there is no space between the last two words. How can I fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String sentence = new String("pay no attention to that man behind the curtain");
    String reversed = "";

    int endIndex = sentence.length()-1;
    for(int i = endIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(sentence.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            reversed += sentence.substring(i, endIndex);
            endIndex = i;
        }
    }
    reversed += sentence.substring(0, endIndex);
    System.out.println(reversed);
}
```

[image]

Comment: StringBuilder has a dedicated method.

Comment: Debug your program to see where that letter gets lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is a better way to reverse the words. But lets look at your program.

> I want my program to output each word on a new line.

If you want to print each word in a new line, you could either add each word to a list of words and print each word in a new line or you could just add "\n" at the end of each word.

> Also notice how the letter "n" is missing from curtain and there is no
> space between the last two words.

This is because the `endIndex` starts at `sentence.length()-1` and `substring` in Java works by extracting from startIndex to endIndex - 1 i.e. endIndex is exclusive and startIndex is inclusive.
You can fix it by declaring `endIndex = sentence.length()` and iterate from i = `sentence.length()-1` to `0`.

With that the code would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String sentence = new String("pay no attention to that man behind the curtain");
    String reversed = "";

    int endIndex = sentence.length();
    for(int i = sentence.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(sentence.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            reversed += sentence.substring(i+1, endIndex) + "\n";
            endIndex = i;
        }
    }
    reversed += sentence.substring(0, endIndex);
    System.out.println(reversed);
  }
```

The better way is :

a) Convert your string to character array

b) Then reverse the whole character array which would become :

```
niatruc eht dniheb nam taht ot noitnetta on yap
```

c) Then reverse the letters between each space in-place.

d) You will get back the new character array that represents:

```
curtain the behind man that to attention no pay
```

and you can construct a string from the new character array.

Comment: It works! Thank you for such a detailed reply and clarifying my errors. I'm new to this and have been trying for hours to figure out where i went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code out:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class ReverseString
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 System.out.println("Enter string to reverse:");
 
 Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
 String str = read.nextLine();
 String reverse = "";
 
 
 for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
 {
 reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
 }
 
 System.out.println("Reversed string is:");
 System.out.println(reverse);
 }
}
```